# SQL Sub Query with Average

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to answer the following question: List the transactions along with the names of the customers that brought in an investment amount higher than the average investment amount for each product line.

A sample of my data is as follows:

ProductLine Table

```
ProductLineID  ProdLine
1              Annuity
2              Disability Insurance
3              Life Insurance
```

Product Table

```
Product     SupID   Commission PLID
10 Payments  107    45         3
20 Payments  107    45         3
Accent-Life  120    35         3
```

Transaction Table has the following columns

```
mSRSnum  mClientLName mClientFname mProduct mAmount
```

My code is as follows. The code spits out a too many values error. Is there another way to answer the question above?

```
  select mSRSnum, mclientFname, mClientLname
  From Transaction
  where mamount > (select Prodline, AVG(mAmount) from Productline
  group by Prodline)
```

Comment: what is the question, again?

Comment: @T.S. the question is: List the transactions along with the names of the customers that brought in an investment amount higher than the average investment amount for each product line.

Comment: Would you please show us sample data for all 3 tables, and the corresponding expected results, so we are sure to understand your requirement clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select mSRSnum, mclientFname, mClientLname
from (select t.*,
             avg(mAmount) over (partition by productline) as avg_mAmount
      from Transaction t
     ) t
where mAmount > avg_mAmount;
```